# How to prevent a window is minimized in java

Tags: java

I'm working on java and I need to create a window that can not be minimized, even by pressing Win + D or click the bottom right corner windows. It is possible? I need some help, I've never tried. Thank You

Comment: This is a OS level function, you will need to first investigate if it's possible to do this at a native level and if it is, figure out how to implement using something like JNI/JNA

Comment: thanks I will investigate on that.I thought it would be easier for recently downloaded a .exe program to just that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);` ?

Comment: thanks for the input, I really had not tried it, I just did and this is what comes closest to what I need, really thank you. Although I still can avoid minimize the window by pressing Win + D.